# ¿Cómo puedo almacenar y usar un token en localstorage con proyecto en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, api, web, local-storage

Tengo una duda respecto al tema del access_token para mi web en **Laravel**. 
Estoy consumiendo mi API y realizando una función que captura el token de autorización para que un usuario pueda lograr acceder a las distintas rutas (según tengo entendido cuando se trabaja en web se usan sessions, pero al consumir una API se basa en el tema del token). Entonces, cada vez que necesito usar una función debo llamar a la que captura el token, pasarlo por el header y así se va generando uno nuevo constantemente, lo cual no es la idea. Leí por ahí que debía almacenarse en localstorage o cookies para que sea el mismo token usado hasta que expire o el usuario cierre sesión, pero no sé si es lo correcto o el como hacerlo, tengo entendido que en este caso debo usar js pero no me manejo en el tema.

Si alguien pudiera ilustrarme un poquito más respecto a cómo debería hacerlo, alguna guía o algo por ahí estaría muy agradecido.

Saludos!

Comment: Por el lado de laravel, tendrías que implementar un sistema de autenticación como puede ser el basico que explican en la doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication o como también ahí recomiendan passport https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport, también hay otras librerías, como jwt. Lo que preguntas del frontend, entiendo que ya estas consumiendo la api, pero no dices cómo. Sin algo en concreto desde donde partir, son muchas las posibilidades

Comment: Al final terminé cambiandome a passport, probaré suerte a ver que tal. Saludos

Comment: Pudiste solucionar? tengo el mismo problema en la autenticacion de usuarios con api y no con la tabla user de lavel